# How to use base constructor data to another constructor in the same class?

Tags: c#, console-application

while trying to call base constructor it throw error like "object doesn't contain constructor that take one argument"

```
    public string FirstName { get;private set; }
    public string LastName { get;private set; }

    public Employee(string firstName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public Employee(string firstName,string lastName):base(firstName)//error
    {
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public string SayHello()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to call the Employee constructor?

Comment: As well as the answer from Dmitry, you might want to consider going in the *other* direction - make the "partial" constructors delegate to a "full" constructor which sets all properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd probably want to call *current clas*s constructor, not a *base class* constructor:

```
public Employee(string firstName, string lastName): this(firstName) // this, not base
{
    LastName = lastName;
}
```